# Unet for medical image segmentation

Tags: keras, neural-network, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm working with Unet and different variations of it for medical image segmentation, I have done it on a dataset with skin lesion and got some good results and prediction. To further my experiments I want to see how it performs on another dataset and I chose a Brain Tumor dataset but the problem is that the results are awful, I don't even get a prediction, my metrics for IoU and Dice coeff are close to 0. I am wondering what is the cause of the problem: how I process the dataset images or do I have to change the Unet model according to the new dataset?

Unet model:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Concatenate, concatenate, UpSampling2D, Lambda, Activation
from keras import Model
from keras import backend as K


def unet(Image_size):
    inply = Input(Image_size)

    conv1 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inply)
    conv1 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.2)(pool1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.2)(pool2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv3)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.2)(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.2)(pool4)

    convm = Conv2D(2 ** 10, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4)
    convm = Conv2D(2 ** 10, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(convm)

    tran5 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 9, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(convm)
    conc5 = Concatenate()([tran5, conv4])
    conv5 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.1)(conv5)

    tran6 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 8, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(drop5)
    conc6 = Concatenate()([tran6, conv3])
    conv6 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)
    drop6 = Dropout(0.1)(conv6)

    tran7 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 7, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(drop6)
    conc7 = Concatenate()([tran7, conv2])
    conv7 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)
    drop7 = Dropout(0.1)(conv7)

    tran8 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 6, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(drop7)
    conc8 = Concatenate()([tran8, conv1])
    conv8 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)
    drop8 = Dropout(0.1)(conv8)

    outly = Conv2D(2 ** 0, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(drop8)
    model = Model(inputs=inply, outputs=outly, name='U-net')

    return model
```

Preparing and splitting the dataset

```
IMAGES = np.zeros((SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
MASKS = np.zeros((SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1))

images_files = glob('E:\Datasets\BrainTumorSegBW\images\*.png')[:SIZE]
masks_files = glob('E:\Datasets\BrainTumorSegBW\masks\*.png')[:SIZE]

for index, path in enumerate(images_files):
    # img = cv2.imread(path, -1)
    # img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = cv2.resize(img, IMAGE_SIZE)
    img = img / 255.0
    img = img.astype('float')
    IMAGES[index] += img

for index, path in enumerate(masks_files):
    mask = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    mask = cv2.resize(mask, IMAGE_SIZE)
    mask = mask / 255.0
    mask = mask.astype('float')
    mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
    MASKS[index] += mask

IMAGES_train, IMAGES_test, MASKS_train, MASKS_test = train_test_split(IMAGES, MASKS, test_size=0.15, random_state=1)
IMAGES_train, IMAGES_val, MASKS_train, MASKS_val = train_test_split(IMAGES_train, MASKS_train, test_size=0.2,
                                                                    random_state=1)
```

and compilation and training of the model

```
model = unet((256, 256, 3))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', iou_score, dice_score])
#callbacks = [...]
history = model.fit(dataset.images_train, dataset.masks_train, epochs=dataset.epoch, batch_size=dataset.batch_size,
                    validation_data=(dataset.images_val, dataset.masks_val),
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Based on the code above what do you think is the problem of the 2 I said or if there is another I'm not aware of let me know. Ty!